# How store, update global variable in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, global-variables

I have an C#/ASP.NET WebForms app.  On the master page, I display a value from a database field.  For example, like "DEFCON = 3" to let all users know what level we're at (of course, when the value is changed in the database, a user won't pick up the new value until they do a page refresh).  But the value will be the same for everyone.

So I'd obviously prefer NOT to have each user's session hit the database on every page load to check for an updated (a round trip for every user, every page seems very inefficient).  A global variable seems like the way to go (though I'm not sure the most modern/simplest way to do this yet).

But beyond this is updating the global variable if and when the DEFCON value is changed in the database.  How would I trigger the global variable to get updated, especially since the change to the value in the database happens outside of the web app.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: First thoughts: caching on the data provider that gets flushed when the value changes (or a statement is executed that alters the value), [partial page caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z(v=vs.100).aspx) (wrap your level in a user control and cache its output), or (least preferrably) [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx) or application cache.

Comment: Caching is the answer as @Cory suggested. Try some sort of cachedependency which refreshes the cache when the database values change. May be SqlCacheDependency!

Comment: Try SignalR, that is a better choice than Caching for updating the UI

Answer (score 0):

Store data in Application variable.Use Ajax to update variable.